# Why do I get a warning that a latch is generated?

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, latch, state-machines

When I compile my VHDL code, I get the following warning:

```
ADCStateMachine.vhd":337:4:337:7|Latch generated from process for signal StartRowxSN, 
probably caused by a missing assignment in an if or case stmt
```

Why does this happen, and how can I avoid it (I am not very experienced with HDL designs)? This is the code causing the error:

```
architecture Behavioral of ADCStateMachine is

  [...]

  signal StartColxSN, StartColxSP : std_logic;

  [...]

  -- calculate next Row state and outputs
  p_row : process (DividerRowxDP, CountRowxDP, RowSettlexDI, StateRowxDP, DoReadxS,  StateColxDP, ExposurexDI, CountColxDP, ReadCyclexS, ColSettlexDI)

  begin  -- process p_row
    -- default assignements: stay in present state

    StateRowxDN          <= StateRowxDP;
    DividerRowxDN        <= DividerRowxDP;
    CDVSTestSRRowClockxS <= '0';
    CDVSTestSRRowInxS    <= '0';

    CountRowxDN <= CountRowxDP;

    ReadDonexS <= '0';
    RegisterWritexEO <= '0';
    ADCwordWritexE   <= '0';

    case StateRowxDP is
      when stIdle =>
        if DoReadxS = '1' and (StateColxDP = stReadReset or StateColxDP = stReadSignal) then
          StateRowxDN <= stFeedRow;
        end if;
        DividerRowxDN <= (others => '0');
        CountRowxDN   <= (others => '0');
        ReadDonexS    <= '0';
      when stFeedRow =>
        CDVSTestSRRowClockxS <= '1';
        CDVSTestSRRowInxS    <= '1';
        StateRowxDN          <= stColSettle;
        if ReadCyclexS = "00" then
          StartRowxSN <= '1';
        else
          StartRowxSN <= '0';
        end if;
      when stColSettle =>
        if DividerRowxDP >= ColSettlexDI then
            StateRowxDN   <= stInit;
            DividerRowxDN <= (others => '0');
        else
          DividerRowxDN <= DividerRowxDP + 1;
        end if;
      when stInit =>
        if DividerRowxDP >= RowSettlexDI then
          StateRowxDN   <= stWrite;
          DividerRowxDN <= (others => '0');
        else
          DividerRowxDN <= DividerRowxDP + 1;
        end if;
      when stWrite =>
        if ReadCyclexS = "00" then
          if CountColxDP < SizeX then
            RegisterWritexEO <= '1';
          else
            RegisterWritexEO <= '0';
          end if;
        end if;
        DividerRowxDN <= (others => '0');
        StateRowxDN   <= stRowDone;
      when stRowDone =>
        CDVSTestSRRowClockxS <= '1';
        CDVSTestSRRowInxS    <= '0';
        StartRowxSN          <= '0';
        if CountRowxDP >= SizeY-1 then
          StateRowxDN <= stColumnDone;
        else
          StateRowxDN <= stInit;
          CountRowxDN <= CountRowxDP + 1;
        end if;
        DividerRowxDN <= (others => '0');
      when stColumnDone =>
        readDonexS  <= '1';
        if DoReadxS = '0' then
          StateRowxDN <= stIdle;
        end if;   
        
      when others => null;
    end case;

  end process p_row;

  [...]

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only assigning to `StartRowxSN` in some of the `when` blocks.  You either need to assign to it in all of the blocks, or give it a default assignment with the other signals (after the comment `default assignements: stay in present state`).